# Three nested loop over a 2D array

Tags: python, scipy

I have a 2D array, which is basically representing a function `F` that depends on two variables: `F(V,T)`.

```
F(V,T) is a 2D array, represented as F_VT:
F_VT   = [[F(V1), F(V2), F3(V3), ..., F(V11)], -> values for T1
          [F(V1), F(V2), F(V3)], ..., F(V11)], -> values for T2

          ...
          [F(V1), F(V2), F(V3)], ..., F(V11)] -> values for T4

V is a 1D array, V = [V1, V2, V3 ... V11]
T is a 1D array, T = [T1, T2, T3, T4]
P is a 1D array, P = [P1, P2, P3, P4]
```

For a given `F(V,T)`, a new function  `Fb(V,T)` can be calculated:

```
Fb(V,T) = F(V,T) + P*V
```

> For a fixed value of `T` and `P`, I would like to plot `Fb`, and sort out the `V` coordinates where `Fb` reaches the minimum. e.g. for that fixed `T` and `P`, `Fb` reaches the minimum at `V = ...`

I have come out with the following three nested loop:

```
for index_T, Ts in enumerate(T):
 for Ps in P:
  aux_P = []
  for Vs in V:
    Fb_VT = F_VT[index_T][:] + (2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21) * Ps * Vs

    p1 = plt.scatter(V, Fb_VT, color='red', marker="^", s=100)

    plt.pause(0.05)
```

But the curves are not considering the loop over `P`. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

F_VT = [np.array([-941.57370763, -941.57401198, -941.57415914, -941.5741743 ,
       -941.57418547, -941.57409029, -941.57384471, -941.57349143,
       -941.57299666, -941.57242367, -941.57172351]), np.array([-941.59428621, -941.59452901, -941.59467455, -941.59470002,
       -941.59475968, -941.59472847, -941.59457033, -941.59432064,
       -941.5939331 , -941.59347988, -941.59293092]), np.array([-941.64179308, -941.64203825, -941.64223508, -941.642278  ,
       -941.64245276, -941.64254897, -941.6425414 , -941.64245835,
       -941.64223967, -941.64196782, -941.641634  ]), np.array([-941.70391106, -941.70416543, -941.70441939, -941.70448022,
       -941.70477693, -941.70500704, -941.70515626, -941.70524589,
       -941.70520195, -941.70511723, -941.70500381])]

V = np.array([ 60.208589,   60.8721745,  61.4382305,  61.515143,   62.2128025,  62.888581,
               63.567809,   64.250832,   64.937775,   65.6287725,  66.3238705])

T = np.linspace(10.00, 2000.00, 4)
P = np.linspace(1., 10., 4)

plt.figure()

for index_T, Ts in enumerate(T):
    for Ps in P:
        aux_P = []
        for Vs in V:
            Fb_VT = F_VT[index_T][:] + (2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21) * Ps * Vs

            p1 = plt.scatter(V, Fb_VT, color='red', marker="^", label='Calcite I', s=100)
            plt.pause(0.05)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

## You have a math problem

You don't have a code problem, you have a math problem. You can get the complete set of your `P*V` values with the following array operation:

```
((2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21) * P * V[:,None]).reshape(-1)
```

Output:

```
[0.01381011 0.05524043 0.09667075 0.13810107 0.01396231 0.05584926
 0.0977362  0.13962314 0.01409215 0.0563686  0.09864506 0.14092151
 0.01410979 0.05643917 0.09876855 0.14109793 0.01426982 0.05707926
 0.09988871 0.14269816 0.01442482 0.05769928 0.10097374 0.1442482
 0.01458061 0.05832246 0.1020643  0.14580615 0.01473728 0.05894912
 0.10316096 0.1473728  0.01489485 0.05957938 0.10426392 0.14894845
 0.01505334 0.06021336 0.10537338 0.1505334  0.01521278 0.0608511
 0.10648943 0.15212775]
```

Notice how small all of these values are. Now compare these to the values you have in `F_VT`. The values of `P * V` are all in fact roughly 4 orders of magnitude smaller than the values in `F_VT`. This makes sense, since you're multiplying all of your `P * V` values by a constant factor that's on the order of `1e-4`.

The only thing I can suggest is increasing either your `V` or `P` values. Maybe something like `P = np.linspace(1, 1000, 4)`?

## Remove loops and speedup your code through vectorization

This has basically nothing to do with the actual problem in your code, but you can speed things up by replacing your triple-loop with two vectorized operations:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

F_VT = np.array([[-941.57370763, -941.57401198, -941.57415914, -941.5741743 , -941.57418547, -941.57409029, -941.57384471, -941.57349143, -941.57299666, -941.57242367, -941.57172351], 
                 [-941.59428621, -941.59452901, -941.59467455, -941.59470002, -941.59475968, -941.59472847, -941.59457033, -941.59432064, -941.5939331 , -941.59347988, -941.59293092], 
                 [-941.64179308, -941.64203825, -941.64223508, -941.642278  , -941.64245276, -941.64254897, -941.6425414 , -941.64245835, -941.64223967, -941.64196782, -941.641634  ], 
                 [-941.70391106, -941.70416543, -941.70441939, -941.70448022, -941.70477693, -941.70500704, -941.70515626, -941.70524589, -941.70520195, -941.70511723, -941.70500381]])

V = np.array([ 60.208589,   60.8721745,  61.4382305,  61.515143,   62.2128025,  62.888581, 63.567809,   64.250832,   64.937775,   65.6287725,  66.3238705])

T = np.linspace(10.00, 2000.00, 4)
P = np.linspace(1., 10., 4)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

PV = ((2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21) * P * V[:,None]).reshape(-1)
Fb_VT = (F_VT[..., None, :] + PV[None, ..., None]).reshape(-1, F_VT.shape[1])

# looping over the rows of Fb_VT will give results equivalent to the triple loop in the old code
for fbvt in Fb_VT:
    ax.scatter(V, fbvt, color='red', marker="^", label='Calcite I', s=100)

fig.show()
```

This will produce the same output as your old code (though for brevity's sake I've plotted all on the output on a single figure):

[image]